# How to remove rows with non-integer values from pandas series of dtype object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

A dataframe based on a survey about candy has a column for the survey taker's age. Currently, the dtype of this column is object. Some of the values in this column are integers, some are strings (ex. 50+, too old for this). How to delete rows that have strings? Most solutions I've tried haven't worked or only apply to entire dataframes.

As shown in the code below, I've tried using inequalities, converting the column to int and removing null values, and keeping only rows with values that are in a certain subset.

```
df = df[(df['Age'] >= 3) & (df['Age'] <= 100)]

df = df[pd.to_numeric(df.Age, errors='coerce').notnull()]
df = df.dropna(subset = ['Age'])

df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dropna()

a=[]
for i in range(2,101):
    a.append(i)
df = df[~df.Age.isin(a)]
```

I usually get "'>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'" or an unchanged dataframe.

Comment: Does your code works or not? What is wrong with `df = df[pd.to_numeric(df.Age, errors='coerce').notnull()]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
mport pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"age": ["45", "50+", "34 ", "34 years", "too old"], "xyz":[1,4,7,3,6]})
print(df)
df.drop(df.index[df["age"].apply(lambda x: not (x.strip().isnumeric()))], axis=0, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Output:

```py
age  xyz
0        45    1
1       50+    4
2       34     7
3  34 years    3
4   too old    6


   age  xyz
0   45    1
2  34     7

[Program finished]
```